# Toggling opacity of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm making a basic animation which randomly makes objects disappear by setting the style.opacity to 0. This works fine. However, I want to be able to toggle the shapes instead of only making them invisible.

Working code which only makes things invisible:

```
--buttons[obj].style.opacity;
```

Not working code which *should* toggle the visibility:

```
buttons[obj].style.opacity = 1 - buttons[obj].style.opacity;
```

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

[Link to code (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/x9Lk1q8t/6/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your buttons don't have `opacity` style right now, you can check it by:

```
console.log(buttons[obj].style.opacity === ''); // true x36
```

So, when you try to calculate

```
buttons[obj].style.opacity = 1 - buttons[obj].style.opacity;
```

That's mean: you're calculating this formula:

```
buttons[obj].style.opacity = 1 - '' = 1;
```

---

Update example for more explanation about how to get element style in javascript:

```js
btn1.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(this.style.opacity); // ''
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(this.style.opacity); // 0.5
});
```

```css
#btn1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2" style="opacity: 0.5;">btn2</button>
```

Comment: I tried adding 'opacity: 1;' to the css for the buttons but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TorNato https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#Getting_style_information explains under what conditions you can _read_ a style value in the first place.

Comment: I don't really understand most of the code in the demonstration. Could you please explain it a bit more? @CBroe

Comment: Via `element.style` you can only read _inline_ styles, meaning they must have been set inline on that element in the first place - via `style` attribute in the HTML code, or via `element.style.property = "value"` in JavaScript. You can not read values that have been applied by different means, such as a rule from a stylesheet.

Comment: @TorNato I've updated my answer to add more explanation about what @Cbroe is saying. As you can see, both `btn1` and `btn2` have the same `opacity` value 0.5. But when logging, you can only get the value 0.5 in `btn2` button. That's `inline` what he is saying.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you're saying more now.